# WordPress Search using multiple select options and no text search

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, search-form

I'm trying to utilise the searchform.php and search.php templates within WordPress to return search results based on categories of 2 select inputs and no text input. Within this custom searchform.php template I'm also using a hidden field to filter by a specific post type.

Currently the search form will return the selected options within the URL and the post type I'm search for, the issue is that the URL itself it malformed and it placing the 's=' parameter at the end, see the example below.

```
https://dev.warrenpartners.picl.co.uk/?category_service=executive-search&category_sector=financial-services&post_type%5B%5D=insight&s=
```

I'm a bit confused here as I've copied many examples of the base WP searchform template but all seem to have the same issue. See my searchform.php template file below:

```
<form role="search" id="searchform" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" class="flex flex-wrap flex-col">
    <span class="lg:text-6xl text-4xl text-white">Locate our expertise</span>
    <p class="lg:my-8 my-4 text-white lg:text-xl text-lg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed libero ac magna ultricies vulputate eget sed diam. Vestibulum ipsum nisl, varius euismod purus posuere, aliquet facilisis nibh.</p>

    <div class="relative w-full mb-8 search-form-input">
        <select name="category_service" id="Service" class="custom-select sources">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Chair & NED Search">Chair & NED Search</option>
            <option value="executive-search">Executive Search</option>
            <option value="Leadership Coaching">Leadership Coaching</option>
            <option value="Consultancy Services">Consultancy Services</option>
            <option value="Interim Management & Advisory">Interim Management & Advisory</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="relative w-full mb-8 search-form-input">
        <select name="category_sector" id="Sector" class="custom-select sources">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="financial-services">Financial Services</option>
            <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>
            <option value="Retail, Consumer & Wellbeing">Retail, Consumer & Wellbeing</option>
            <option value="Property & Real Estate">Property & Real Estate</option>
            <option value="Technology & Digital">Technology & Digital</option>
            <option value="Professional Services">Professional Services</option>
            <option value="Memberships & NPO's">Memberships & NPOs</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="insight" />
    <div class="relative w-full mt-4">
        <button type="submit" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="searchsubmit" class="btn-red cursor-pointer search-form-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That would obviously be the result of the submit button having `name="s"`.

Comment: That removes the search ability altogether... Ideally I want to loop through my two selected options and populate the name="" attribute with the terms

Comment: Probably because WP checks for the existence of that GET parameter, to trigger the search functionality in the first place ... _"the issue is that the URL itself it malformed"_ - it simply contained a parameter with no value, how exactly is that "malformed"? Are you only having an "optical" issue with this, or what is the actual problem?

Comment: Clearly I don't know, I thought it was malformed? My search results return nothing so instead of acting aggressive some help would be preferred.

Comment: _"My search results return nothing"_ - what have you done to make it _use_ your additional form fields in the search?

Comment: Nothing obviously, I assumed it would pick up the inputs from the search form itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You need to modify the database query yourself - https://wpmudev.com/blog/add-search-by-category-functionality-to-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: I've added this in now and it's able to search by filters, I need these split into two sub categories. The results page is for some reason showing duplicates of all the posts as well causing a serious load issue

Comment: _"I need these split into two sub categories"_ - not sure what that is supposed to mean. // Do you want to find posts that have either the selected service or sector category, or only posts that are categorized as both at the same time? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters shows the different ways to you filter by category/categories.

Comment: I need to find posts that have both categories or individually. I've sorted out the subcategories by using: 

`<?php
 $parent = get_category_by_slug( 'service' );

 $categories = get_categories( array(
  'parent' => $parent->term_id,
 ) );
        ?>
 <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: I would pass the category ID as the option value, rather than the slug. Then you can use those IDs with the `category__in` operator.

Comment: Does the `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '2,6,17,38' ) );` go on the search.php page?

Comment: No, that just illustrates the possible parameters. You still need to manipulate the actual query instance that WP uses via the `pre_get_posts` filter.